# Using fetch to set the state of a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio

I'm trying to build a simple weather widget style component as a introduction to Typescript and React. I have a personal API the send the data correct, fetch is receiving the API call correctly, and it is being parsed into the CurrentWeather object(?) correctly. However, when trying to use the values from CurrentWeather, it breaks.

Here's the entire .tsx file I'm using:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './WeatherWidget.css';

export interface CurrentWeather {
    main: CurrentWeatherData,
    name: string
}

export interface CurrentWeatherData {
    temp: number,
    feels_like: number,
    humidity: number,
    temp_min: number,
    temp_max: number
}

type MyProps = {};
type MyState = {
    temperature: number,
    minTemperature: number,
    maxTemperature: number,
    feelsLikeTemp: number,
    city: string,
    humidity: number
};

class WeatherNow extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        fetch('weatherforecast/today')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CurrentWeather>)
            .then(data => {
                this.state = {
                    temperature: data.main.temp,
                    minTemperature: data.main.temp_min,
                    maxTemperature: data.main.temp_max,
                    feelsLikeTemp: data.main.feels_like,
                    city: data.name,
                    humidity: data.main.humidity
                };

                console.log(this.state);
            });
    }

    render = async () => {
        return (
            <div className="weather-now">
                <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "32px", marginTop: "5px" }}>{this.state.temperature}°</div>
                <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>{this.state.minTemperature}° / {this.state.maxTemperature}°</div>
                <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>Feels Like: {this.state.feelsLikeTemp}°</div>
                <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "25px", marginTop: "10px" }}>{this.state.city}</div>
                <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>Humidity: {this.state.humidity}%</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default WeatherNow;
```

I'm using whatever built-in libraries VS2022 has you use when you create a typescript/react website.

Edit: These are the errors I am getting.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')
    at WeatherNow.render (WeatherWidget.tsx:56:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18451:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18404:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20161:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440:1)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25738:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24662:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24638:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24237:1)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23665:1)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:27061:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:27485:1
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:24400:1)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:27484:1)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:27572:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.tsx:19:1)
    at Module../src/index.tsx (index.tsx:28:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (index.ts:20:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:95
```

```
The above error occurred in the <WeatherNow> component:
    in WeatherNow (at Home.tsx:21)
    in div (at Home.tsx:6)
    in Home (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.tsx:12)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (at Layout.tsx:10)
    in Layout (at App.tsx:11)
    in Unknown (at src/index.tsx:22)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ConnectedRouterWithContext (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at src/index.tsx:21)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')
    at WeatherNow.render (WeatherWidget.tsx:56:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18451:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18404:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20161:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440:1)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25738:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24662:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24638:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24237:1)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23665:1)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:27061:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:27485:1
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:24400:1)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:27484:1)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:27572:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.tsx:19:1)
    at Module../src/index.tsx (index.tsx:28:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (index.ts:20:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:95
```

Same errors are occurring with the first response's suggested code changes.

Comment: Can you all attach the error. It would help to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: dont set state directly, use [this.setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Also, ensure you have a fetching state since the api request is async, meaning your component will mount, and a promise will return once the API call completes. Use a state variable for `fetchingData` and display a loading indicator or some feedback while the API query is busy, and then display your weather-row once its complete. set `fetchingData` to true once the promise completes.

Comment: @Singh3y I added the error messages

Comment: @Gandzal I made the changes almost exactly as Asad suggested below, but I'm still encountering the same issues, I'm really unsure of what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Based on the error message it seems like your network request is not returning any data. Can you check your network log and check the json object returned

Comment: @Singh3y I make the request twice for some reason, but both times the request returns the desired json object, and the state values are correct in the console.log right before we return the weather-now object

Answer (score 0):

use fetch in componentDidMount instead of constructor and use loading state for API Call fetch.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './WeatherWidget.css';

export interface CurrentWeather {
    main: CurrentWeatherData,
    name: string
}

export interface CurrentWeatherData {
    temp: number,
    feels_like: number,
    humidity: number,
    temp_min: number,
    temp_max: number
}

type MyProps = {};
type MyState = {
    temperature: number,
    minTemperature: number,
    maxTemperature: number,
    feelsLikeTemp: number,
    city: string,
    humidity: number
};

class WeatherNow extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
       this.state={
       loading:true,
       temperature:0 ,
                minTemperature:0 ,
                maxTemperature: 0,
                feelsLikeTemp: 0,
                city: 0,
                humidity:0
       }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
       fetch('weatherforecast/today')
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CurrentWeather>)
        .then(data => {
           let d = {
                temperature: data.main.temp,
                minTemperature: data.main.temp_min,
                maxTemperature: data.main.temp_max,
                feelsLikeTemp: data.main.feels_like,
                city: data.name,
                humidity: data.main.humidity
            };
            this.setState({...d,loading:false})
            
        });
       }
    render() {
    if(this.state.loading) return (<div>Loading...</div>)
    return (
        <div className="weather-now">
            <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "32px", marginTop: "5px" }}>{this.state.temperature}°</div>
            <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>{this.state.minTemperature}° / {this.state.maxTemperature}°</div>
            <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>Feels Like: {this.state.feelsLikeTemp}°</div>
            <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "25px", marginTop: "10px" }}>{this.state.city}</div>
            <div className="weatherWidgetRow" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>Humidity: {this.state.humidity}%</div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default WeatherNow;
```